# Power BI visual - select rows by min variable value in a group

Tags: powerbi

I'm beginner in powerbi. My question is: Can I select rows in powerbi visual, by min(value) from a variable in a group? For example I have a dataset:

| row_id | group_1 | var | group_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1.2 | X |
| 2 | A | 1.3 | Y |
| 3 | A | 1.4 | Z |
| 4 | B | 2 | X |
| 5 | B | 3 | Y |

From this dataset I want select rows 1 and 4. In R language I can do it with

```
dataset<-dataset %>%group_by(group_1)%>%dplyr::slice(which.min(var))
```

How can I do this in powerbi visual?

Thanks